# Wrap mat-select options to fit to control's width

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use below css to wrap mat-select options and working fine.

The same css is also applying to few auto-complete options so auto-complete not properly wrapping that means, option is hiding with other option of upside and downside[image].

```
.mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
  height: unset;
}

.mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

What changes are required in this code?

Comment: See this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnr1yt

Comment: also this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oggceh

Comment: mat option's text should wrap to next line whenever text is long.

Comment: it will be shown as `your-text-is-too-long` as `your-text-is...`

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ndtstg

Comment: Yes, it is default but I want to wrap this. The above css code works well with other mat-select options but with mat-autocomplete

Comment: Yes, your 3rd link css and my code both are same and works with mat-select but not with mat-autocomplete

Comment: yes got that....

Comment: You can also use a tooltip to show the full text?

Comment: ha but my client does not like it, he wanted text to be wrapped. Because, tooltip will show even for short text.

Comment: Okay! i am investigating will update once done

Answer (score 0):

Set width for `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>` wrapper tag like:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS:

```
.example-width {
   width: 50%; -- or the width you want for auto-complete
}
```

[`Working-Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oggceh)